# Overwriting or Recreating Variables in Power Virtual Agent

Tags: powerapps, power-virtual-agents

I've been trying to create several greeting topics in PVA, to allow for the user to dive straight into the conversation and say things like "hi Id like to report a bug" or "i have question" and have the bot then recognize that the user would like to either report an issue or ask a question.

To capture this correctly, I would need the bot to have ability to re-use the same variable name which it doesn't seem to allow.

Example:

The user says "Hi I have an issue"
Bot responds "Good morning, would like you to report an issue with the XRS platform?" (yes no stored in [bool_issue]
If yes, "Issue" is stored in [cat_action]
If no, the bot asks "Oh I misunderstood. What would you like to do instead?" with option "Ask Question" or "Request feature".
I would like to have that answer stored in [cat_action] as well.

How would I go about this, to re-use or overwrite the [cat_action] variable?

Answer (score 0):

Power Virtual Agents has a concept called bot variables. That might be useful in your scenario.

Over here is a Microsoft doc about how you can setup a variables as a bot variable:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-virtual-agents/authoring-variables-bot#reuse-a-variable-across-topics-by-setting-it-as-a-bot-variable

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this exact same issue. PVA doesn't seem to allow direct overwrite of variables within the PVA environment. The only way I've found to hack around this limitation is having the variable set from an outside source and updating the outside source i.e. dataverse, excel, etc... For example: Create a flow that initializes a variable catAction as a bot.var where the value of this variable is the output of a dataverse entry then anytime it needs updating run a flow that changes the dataverse entry value and re-call the flow that initializes the variable. Hope this helps.

Bot framework is another option but if your like me and only have the PVA for TEAMS license, Bot framework isn't available.